# ASP.NET forms authentication encoded in URL

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble with I guess Forms Authentication..

Site runs perfect can login and log out..  but after a while (this is not a specific time frame) suddenly URLs start to look like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/(A(EvoNg_065oCKJ1l_AcU4ND7Uzkm05wugwbYu4jiKb-_24aJmbmE_r5djE-mw9b_3tvEBOLIH1f64rrtq6RZOSFto_o0MaN-3edRpjH2Bfn8uBnrUFhv2xmk4_9oLXHVEt-Dg5BfdPA3VprkCIixmbhr2KPs1))/Default.aspx
```

What does this encoding (A) mean...  is it the authorization ticket or Anonymous user ticket or what is it.
The funny thing is that it stays there and also include the encoding in all links on the page. Until at recycle the application pool for the site... when it is gone..... and it just starts over again after a while....

Anyone to point me in the right direction. Site is ASP.NET 4, using form auth and deployed on a IIS7

Please help...

Best regards

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a [cookieless session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) which you might have configured. Look for the following in your web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

Also checkout if [cookieless Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_cookielessforms) is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked and I have cookieless="false" for this setting. I guess this means that it should never embed any session info in the URL right?

Comment: @hgsdc, are cookies enabled in your browser? Also checkout if cookieless Forms Authentication is not enabled : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_cookielessforms

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry for getting back so late. It has to do with sessions. However, I turned off every kind of AppPool and WorkerProcess recycling on the IIS and it worked from that point on.